# Is there any possibility of getting “country name” using “currency code” in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I need to get the **country name** using **currency code** which i have.

Is there any possiblity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible.
Currencies do not "belong" to countries.
Let's take for example Euro (code EUR).
What country do you expect to get from this? France, Germany, or maybe Greece?

Comment: you are right. Still i dint get any solution

Comment: @vinothavn A possible solution would be to create your own module where you associate different currencies to different countries. Then query the values in your module table and get the countries associated to a specific currency