# How to get country name using currency code in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, currency, countries

I want to get country name using currency code. For ex. if currency code is INR then, It should be return country name : India.

How to do that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: check this link --- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/15841/85907 is that not possible  or check again this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/37788175/11908692... first link think is right

Comment: I already read that.